# What reflexive operator algebras are there besidesB(H) and Nest?

Tags: operator-algebras

I want to think about single element rank on some reflexive operator algebras,but I’m not sure what reflexive operator algebras are there besides B(H) and nest.

Comment: I think it would be nice if you give more context (in my experience many $C^\ast$-algebraist don't know what a reflexive operator algebra (or a nest algebra is).